How do I know where on my desktop videos recorded using the Screenshot Toolbar are stored?
I am attempting to record my screen using the Screenshot Toolbar on my Mac.
I know that screen recordings using the Screenshot Toolbar on my Mac are saved on my Desktop, but I do not know where on my Desktop the screen recordings are stored.

They should be on your Desktop.  After making a recording, open Terminal then type ls ~/Desktop. Do you see the files?

Have you tried locating the file using a Finder window and navigating to your Desktop folder?
